# Highcharts vertical line (crosshair) logic

Tags: highcharts

I was wondering if it possible to activate the vertical line that appears and highlights points when hovering over the graph?

For example in this graph: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare
-> When hovering over the graph lines, the suitable point in each series is highlighted and a vertical line connects between them.
I need an event to trigger this line and highlight the points for a specific `x` value.

Comment: What do you mean with 'specific x value'? The Fiddle highlights the certain values.

Comment: Yes, it highlights the values when I hover over them, though I want a way to activate it without hovering over the graph. For example, when selecting a button a specific set of vertical points are highlighted.

Answer (score 24):

This vertical line appears by default on highstock but on highcharts it's null by default. You can enable it setting tooltip crosshairs like [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/crosshairs-x/).
To highlight all your series on the same y value you have to set shared as true like **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/SuDP9/)**.
Code:

```
tooltip: {
    crosshairs: {
        color: 'green',
        dashStyle: 'solid'
    },
    shared: true
}
```

You can style your crosshairs looking the following [reference](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#tooltip--crosshairs).

Comment: Hi, @Ricardo Alvaro Lohmann. Why did you reject my suggested edit? Current version of Highcharts is deprecating using of `crosshairs` on `tooltip`. My edit wasn't _promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive_. Or, is it possible I'm wrong? And if 'yes' - so where I am wrong?

Comment: @BohdanKuts appears to be right, it seems you should now use [xAxis.crosshair](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.crosshair) and yAxis.crosshair instead of tooltip.crosshairs.